# JBoss Portals and e-commerce

Tags: e-commerce, portal, jboss-portal

I have a requirement to build branded e-commerce sites that have their own urls but are on the same installation.

I've been looking at DNN, and Jboss portals as well as the new GateIn collaboration between Jboss portals and Exo.  I really like what I see in comparison to DNN, which looks a bit rough in comparison but I haven't seen anything with respect to Jboss portals ecommerce.

What has been peoples experience with using the Jboss portals or GateIn etc, for branded portals or using Jboss for selling?

UPDATE:  cost is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will help you...and I have not used Jboss portal in a production environment. If you have the budget to do this sort of thing...I think no-one does it better then Vignette (I know it can be a bitch sometimes being complex and all but it's designed to do EXACTLY the stuff you want to do...but since they are commercial and have an excellent support staff...so that should not be a problem.)

but again you can do it with Jboss portal too...I have internal developers working off it spinning portlets and deploying them to vignette.

PS: I am not from vignette..It is just that this company's management sucks but the product is great.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that cost is any issue.  I will look at Vignette though.  Truthfully DNN is probably fine but I don't like the patchwork feel it has.